# Using reflection, how can I find the Method that takes arguments defined in the reflected library itself?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a library written in .NET461 and I would like to call a method in that library using reflection

The class itself looks something like ...

```
public class ClassA {
}
...
public class ClassB {
  public MethodA( ClassA val )
  {
    ..
  }  

  public MethodA( List<ClassA> list )
  {
    ..
  }  
}
```

My calling exe is a .NET48 executable...

(removed validation and some code for brevity)

```
// get the library
var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom( "...myAssembly.dll" );

// instantiate ClassB
var instance = asm.CreateInstance( "ClassB" )

// look for that class type so we can get the method "MethodA"
var type = asm.GetExportedTypes().FirstOrDefault( t => t.Name == "ClassB" ); 

// look for all the methods called "MethodA"
// this call works and I can see I have 2 methods with that name
var methods = type.GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "MethodA").ToList();

// look for the method just by that name.
// Here I get an error as there are 2 methods with the same name.
var method = type.GetMethod( "MethodA");
```

It is possible to get the method if I pass the parameters but the 'type' in the list is supposed to be a list of `List<ClassA>`

How can I find the method with a parameter of `List<ClassA>` when `ClassA` itself is defined in the library and not in my executable.

```
...
var methodA = type.GetMethod("MethodA", new []
          {
            typeof(List<ClassA>>)                  // <<<< ClassA is not defined here. 
                                                   //      It is defined in the library
          } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a type variable of `ClassA` the same way as you get it for `ClassB` then construct parameter type and get needed method:

```
var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom( "...myAssembly.dll" );
var assemblyTypes = asm.GetExportedTypes();

var classAType = assemblyTypes.FirstOrDefault( t => t.Name == "ClassA" );
var classBType = assemblyTypes.FirstOrDefault( t => t.Name == "ClassB" );

var instance = asm.CreateInstance( "ClassB" ); // or Activator.CreateInstance(classBType);

// construct parameter type - List<ClassA> type

var listOpenGenericType = typeof(List<>);

// List<ClassA>
var listClosedGenericType = listOpenGenericType.MakeGenericType(classAType); 

// find the method
var method = classBType
    .GetMethods()
    .Where(m => m.Name == "MethodA")
    .FirstOrDefault(m => 
    {
        var parameters = m.GetParameters();
                                     
        return parameters.Length == 1 && parameters.First().ParameterType == listClosedGenericType);
    });

if (method != null)
{
    // call method
    method.Invoke(instance, yourList); // pass list
}

// ...
```